# Angular Material Select, selectionChange not firing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have prepared example (**Angular Material Select**):

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhwtam-lpwjaw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.ts)

> I have set value on ngOnInIt for mat-select, but **selectionChange event** is
> not firing. Whenever I set value to mat-select with value property, I want that
> selectionChange is fired, and I want to do some work on
> selectionChange.

selectionChange is firing on manual user selection, but not on setting value.

Why selectionChange event is not firing?

Is there any other event or approach to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhwtam-qxkf2c?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html) The `selectionChange` event fires only when the html element is changed by a user and not by backend data change. You can use `Viewchild` as a way to manually call a function:

```
@ViewChild("changeEl") el!: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.selectedFood = this.foods[0].value;
        this.selectionChangeTax(this.el)
      }
```

HTML:

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="selectionChangeTax($event)" #changeEl [(value)]="selectedFood">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: what is another options to call selectionChange event? is there any event? I dont want to call explicitly selectionChange

Answer (score 0):

You can use valueChange if you want to know about all the changes.

on ngOnInit

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({ firstName: [this.firstName], lastName: [this.lastName] });

 this.myForm.controls['firstName'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => { console.log(value); });
```

Comment: can you give me working example? because i have trien valueChange event, but its not working

Comment: No this is form control valuchanges event. I want mat-select event

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. However I have prepared StackBlitz where I use `RxJS` to subscribe to new value in the select. Whenever the values gets changed, next callback in the subscription will be fired. See `console` for output.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhwtam-udkedb